# SQL query for display one value only once which having multiple record

Tags: sql

i have this type of record

```
project   vendor  value
------------------------
A          HDFC   23
B          HDFC   20
A          HDFC   52
c          CITI   56
------------------------
```

output is

```
project   vendor   value
---------------------------
A         HDFC      23
-          -        52
B          -        20
c         CITI      56
---------------------------
```

Comment: Has to be done from *Application* side not in Database

Comment: @Prdp:it's is not possible to done on application side

Comment: what did you try? Please show some effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS SQL :

```
select project,vendor,value from (
select 
row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project) as number,
case 
    when row_number() over (partition by project order by vendor) = 1 then project 
    else '-'
end as project, 
case 
    when row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project) = 1 then vendor 
    else '-'
end as vendor,
value
from [Vendors]
) as S
order by number
```

it is working like you want !

Comment: @@merrais:it is working good in sql server ,thank you so much,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is standard ANSI SQL:

```
select project, 
       case 
            when row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project) = 1 then vendor 
            else '-' 
       end as vendor,
       value
from the_table
order by project, row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f77b0/1

Comment: above mention is not supporting,i am using sql server,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,showing error-  The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @kiranbabu: then you didn't copy my example because my answer **does** contain an `order by` for the `row_number()` function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY project, vendor) SNo
INTO #ordered
FROM YourTable

UPDATE o
SET o.project = CASE WHEN last.project = o.project THEN '-' ELSE o.project END, o.vendor = CASE WHEN last.vendor = o.vendor THEN '-' ELSE o.vendor END
FROM #ordered o 
LEFT OUTER JOIN #ordered last ON last.SNo = o.SNo - 1

SELECT project, vendor, value 
FROM #ordered
```

Comment: Why the unnecessary intermediate table with an UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

A small variation from the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37745520/2772061) to get closer to the expected output

```
select project, 
       case  when row_number() over (partition by project) = 1 then project 
            else '-'
       end as new_project, 
       case when row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project) = 1 then vendor 
            else '-'
       end as vendor,
       value
from projects
order by project, row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project);

project new_project vendor  value
A       A           HDFC    23
A       -           -       52
B       B           -       20
c       c           CITI    56
```

Comment: Good point. I overlooked the repetition of the `project` values

Answer (score 0):

Using the first Answer I think we should add the same logic on the project column perfectly match the original question :

```
select 
case 
    when row_number() over (partition by project) = 1 then project 
    else '-'
end as project, 
case 
    when row_number() over (partition by vendor order by project) = 1 then vendor 
    else '-'
end as vendor,
value
from projects
order by row_number() over (partition by vendor)
```

Comment: @@merrais:showing error "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause. i am using sql server

Comment: I posted another reply to sql server !